# What to do when you have forgotten password of your own profile

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts

I have asked this previously also. Again posting it since I am in deep trouble

I had an account named **learning maths** https://math.stackexchange.com/users/178656/learning-maths

The problem is I have forgotten the password of this account and more importantly the gmail account's password with which I opened it.

I had posted many questions which are important for me. Can someone help me to recover my account.

Though I remember the e-mail with which I opened this account, I no longer remember its password. I have failed to recover it also.

Is there any way to recover that account or merge that account with this account of me.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: As a remark, I would start using a password manager.

Answer (score 3):

In order to recover an account you will have to somehow verify that you have ownership of it.

The easiest route would be via the [Account Recovery tool](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) which will send a recovery email to the associated address ([provided it is not with one of several disposable email address providers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277999)). Of course, in order for this to work you need access to that email address.

If you no longer have access to the email account you can fill out the [Contact Us](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) form. Choosing the "I lost my password" option will not automatically send you to the Account Recovery tool, so it is probably your best option. You can then describe your problem, and try to somehow prove ownership of the account in the form. These will be looked at by humans and they may want to get more information from you, so also provide an email address that you *can* access. Of course there is no guarantee they will believe your claim.

Account merges would also go through that Contact Us form (using the "I need to merge user profiles" option). Again, ownership of the accounts will have to be verified, the usual way probably via email. Describing your situation may convince SE to allow other forms of proof. Again, I give no guarantee that this will actually result in the merging of the accounts.